# How to update Electron JS webview?

Tags: javascript, electron

I was making my own web browser in Electron JS. Everything was working properly but whatsapp web didn't opened, it shows to update Chrome. I know that electron uses chrome but the version is very backdated so if anyone knows how to update the webview of electron then please suggest a solution...

I didn't tried anything yet to solve this!